# This mis-aligned border is going to give me nightmares!

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

Consider the following:
[image]

See that misaligned border?  Now you're going to have nightmares too! I suppose in a perfect, happy world, that border would be aligned with the rest of the boxes there?

Skeptical? Just head over to your profile and you'll see! That **IMPACT** box is a good 4-6px lower than the **BADGES** and **REPUTATION** boxes

Comment: Agree, 4-6px is unacceptable, it should be 6-8px ...

Comment:  oh please no. I’m begging you.

Comment: I'm more disturbed by the fact that red oval is clearly not freehand :p

Comment: @JonClements see? SEE?! It's contagious. It's going to start infecting designs everywhere!

Comment: Once seen, never unseen.

Comment: [muhahaha!](http://i.imgur.com/AVgVe1L.png)

Comment: Personally I'm a lot more concerned about the emoji.

Comment: @JoshCaswell let the hate flow through you 

Comment: I'm totally on board with circle shaped circles.

Comment: Also pretty disturbing: why is part of the oval cropped out from the picture?? 

Comment: @user2314737, because it's more than 4-6px under!

Comment: I am waiting for the next bug with the title *muhahaha!* :P @AlonEitan

Comment: I will never look at a user profile again.

Comment: Be thankful you're not using IE11. On my screen all three boxes have a different height.

Comment: Someone is a bit OCD or is that DCO.... lol.

Comment: This is thy type of thing that make the 80/20 rule a fact.

Comment: No one should be using IE. Ever.

Comment: Well, not in IE only,  different heights appear on FireFox too.

Comment: Sure, just as long as no one is using IE.

Comment: Yep in FF everything is fine : none of the boxes has the same height, and the difference between the smallest and the tallest is `6.8px`. So for a fix, use Firefox.

Comment: Obviously the different heights of those boxes are intentional, and it's Chrome breaking here by aligning two of the boxes?

Comment: I think it’s more likely that the boxes aren’t designed to be aligned at all, and the fact that the left two are sometimes, is a fluke. But it looks odd, so something should be done to standardize their height.

Comment: I have noticed it before. What I did was just shrugging my shoulder and moved on. It is not problem. I've added the last sentence because the thought to see you having more nightmares may appeal me.

Comment: I’m about to sleep actually right now. I’m terrified of the mis-alignment monster 

Comment: @Namphibian No, it's CDO - that way, all the letters are in order *as they should be.*

Comment: Lol point made. I want a person like you on my QA team. I salute you sir.

Comment: Nice, now I see that in Chrome there are many thing misaligned in that page. Makes me feel better about my own user interfaces with crooked placements.

Comment: My organisation enforces Internet Explorer, so I see [3 different alignments](http://i.imgur.com/J8790wa.png), 3 and 6 pixels apart.

Comment: @Kaiido I'm using firefox and they are misaligned as well. It seems to depend on the content of the tab, not only just the browser

Comment: I suggest this to be immediately fixed by changing the 4-6px into 6d4+4 px. It should make everyone feel like Addison, or better!

Comment: Okay so what's the question? :p

Comment: @Coldspeed I see you're trying to reason with meta. You should totally drop that and try jQuery.

Comment: [Here is a soothing image that should help with the nightmares.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgqut.jpg)

Comment: @Will. Stop it.

Comment: @brandonscript There is [no stop ping](https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8685/16712015610_162b53849a_b.jpg) us now :)

Comment: This post makes me so happy.

Comment: @Will That pizza eater is a criminal. This is just not okay.

Comment: Maybe they were created by two different developers or teams, e.g. team `BadgesBox` and team `ImpactBox`, and they communicate through `slack` with `giphy` enabled. So the `height` information got lost somewhere in a pile of gif images.

Comment: there's more misaligned gross-ness on the `unanswered` tab for tagged questions

Comment: The vertically misaligned ~ character in the Impact box is keeping me awake. I dislike the ~ character.

Comment: Using `height` instead of `min-height` would fix this...

Comment: The box is misaligned on purpose for maximum mental IMPACT

Comment: You have impacted too many people, making the ~2.2 label too big. You are too skilled ;)

Comment: Not my fault that I'm the target of ~2.2M serial downvoters! :P

Comment: @Kaiido - How in the world does one get 6.8 px?!  Has someone figured out a way to display partial pixels and not told me about it?

Comment: @AgapwIesu antialiasing maybe ? Note that px is not exactly a pixel per se, it's an magic CSS unit. In CSS you rarely deal with pixels, it's a job for the monitors. (Imagine if you had to set different rules for each screen resolutions). And the [DOMRect](https://drafts.fxtf.org/geometry-1/#domrect) used to describe the coordinates and size of an element should return floats.

Comment: Hi, My name is Adrian Monk and I approve this thread

Comment: I also [reported this back in 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250090/166789) and it was allegedly fixed back then. Fake bugfix apparently! Sad!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the words of the great and wise doge…

[image: doge says]

The community's concern for the seemingly smallest details speaks to the concern you have for Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network. When I first saw this post, I took a quick peek into this anomaly. Could I simply add `display: flex;` to the overall wrapper and be done with it? Well yes, that would work…mostly.

Yet as I explored this area further I discovered a number of other issues as well. And given that I was in-between projects and needed something I could work on but drop rather quickly if need be, this was a perfect little project.

After looking at the highlight boxes a bit further, here are the issues I found (beyond mis-aligned borders):

- **Use of CSS sprites.** We've been actively moving away from CSS sprites in favor of inline SVG icons. There are a number of icons within this area which have been converted to SVGs.
- **One-off icons in use.** And while we're updating icons to inline SVGs, we should use icons that are used in other areas of Stack Overflow.
- **Incorrect colors, font-sizes, line-heights, and spacing.** A whole bunch of inconsistency here. The Stack Overflow Design team has been (slowly) standardizing these items and we update the design accordingly.
- **Poor color contrast with the badge progress bar.** We're updating the badge and privilege progress bars so that the copy is easier to read and you can see the badge dot / icon better now.
- **Older progress bar styles.** Again, since we're in here in, let's also update the progress bars to a newer, updated look.
- **A heavy mixture of layout and style coding within the CSS.** Two years ago we didn't have robust grid system in place  and flexbox hadn't been fully implemented yet across all modern browsers . But oh happy day, flexbox is now a thing  and we have a grid system  . All the old highly specific layout CSS we can now tear out. Gone are the floats, magical fixed widths, and confusing absolutely positioned items in favor of a flexbox grid system.
- **The popup badge/tag selector search box was always breaking.** Over the years we've fixed the search input within the badge/tag selector popup multiple times for various communities. It *just* fit, so when a community's input style had slightly more padding or a larger font-size, it all fell apart. Now with the power of flexbox  , this can be fixed forever… thankfully  .

As you can see, these mis-aligned borders hint at deeper, larger issues. And while this may seem like a small matter, it's actually something we do care very much about here at Stack. Not only do we want Stack Overflow to be the best product out there, but we also want clean, re-usable, well-commented code. This allows the various developers and designers that work here to understand why things are the way they are and can properly address or improve things without breaking things or re-inventing the same thing elsewhere.

Here are some obligatory screenshots to compare and contrast the old and the new highlight boxes…

#### Before Highlight Boxes

[image: Activity Boxes Before]

#### After Highlight Boxes

[image: Activity Highlight After]

So there you go. Misaligned borders are now gone and so are a lot of other little oddities. This has now been pushed to production. If you see any issues, please let us know using the [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) [design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design) [profile-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/profile-page) combo.

Comment: Bless you for fixing dis!!!!

Comment: Omg it’s like a dream come true 

Comment: Here is a  for all your hard work and dedication to design precision. Unrelated: autocarrot tried to change "precision" into "prison". I was tempted to leave it.

Comment: Thanks for fixing this! The alignment between the questions and tags sections, mentioned [in this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/350913/4660897), is still off though. Can that be fixed as well?

Comment: @brandonscript Autocarrot will get you every time.

Answer (score 87):

[image]

Answer to your nightmare hope this nightmare overrides the one you posted

Comment: Might be worthwhile expanding that image a bit so people have some context. But yeah, just noticed that *all* those tabs are out of alignment. It's almost like it's deliberately done. :| http://i.imgur.com/sFSO3F2.png

Comment: atleast you have a good reputation to showoff :P

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/h5zUM one more odd placement "question feed"

Comment: Edit your answer and add a red freehand circle please. I do not understand this image.

Comment: *This* misalignment can be explained by the section sorting in the `<div class="subtabs user-panel-subtabs">`.  Example: The `Accounts` section has no sort option. While `Badges` can be sorted by `recent`, `class`, or `name`. Sort options adds 4 px to the `subheader` height. True for all of these subheaders.

Comment: @OhBeWise I don't understand your point. It doesn't explain why it is not possible to fix the misalignment or why it is ok to keep it

Comment: How dare you! 

Comment: To me the tables are aligned on the beginning of the box, not at the line after the title. Which is affected by having options to order the list inside that box

Comment: @TJ I agree, it *is* possible to fix and shouldn't be kept this way.  My point was more to say why this *answer* isn't really an answer - but another alignment issue - one that stems from the `div` element I pointed out. The OP misalignment is similar, but one does not answer the other.

Comment: @GillBates [you're welcome](http://imgur.com/fcMGcOo)

Answer (score 54):

They are everywhere.

Presumably, some of the alignment could be justified as stacking items of variable height, but I can't possibly see the reasoning behind this:

[image]

Larger view

[image]

Comment: While this is a dupe of Hari's answer, you get my upvote because of the freehand arrows. In both cases they are caused by the addition of tabs in one heading but not the other.

Comment: This is a good point.  And by point, I mean arrow, and good, I mean freehand.

Answer (score 52):

This is SO's systematic approach to suppress the natural urge for organization in the typical programmer's brain.

They offer varying degrees, from the beginner-level difference between the badges and impact box to the professional OCD `1px` difference between the reputation and badges box.

P.S. The fix to the problem (aligning all three boxes) simply is:

```
#top-cards{display:flex;}
```

[image: misaligned boxes]

[image: zoomed image]

Comment: Totally stealing professional OCD.

Comment: This answer is missing a picture of a prarie dog turning towards the reader with a surprised look on its face.

Comment: @DanNeely OCD spotted.

Comment: @Christoph No. No! NO! NO!!!  I don't have OCD, that disease's letters aren't in the proper alphabetical order they way they should be and are with CDO.

Answer (score 18):

**Fix:**

```
.subtabs a, .filter a {
    padding: 6px 8px;
}
```

**Preview:**
[image: Issue fixed]

Comment: Nice fix for a problem the OP did not bring up originally;)

Comment: Hey, anything that reduces nightmares is ok by me

Comment: Why don't you add `.impact-card { padding-bottom: 16px; }` which will fix the original problem

Comment: @CalvT븃 actually, that's a bad fix, since all three boxes have different gaps and they differ by variable amounts depending on the browser used. See my answer for a more robust/reliable fix (assuming you use an up-to-date browser that actually supports flexbox).

Answer (score 16):

Also @Christoph, being OCD is being OCD.
[image]

Comment: I have never seen such passionate rage about misaligned elements :) Your answer, and all the others, are an eye-opener to me

Comment: Argl, how could I miss this!!!! ಠ︹ಠ

Comment: What's all this with the black boxes??? Long live the red circles!

Comment: @CalvT븃 I think you mean *free hand* red circles

Comment: @Frakcool I did, but *Long live the freehand red circles* seemed a bit of a mouthful