# Unnecessary line of space on Activity page

Tags: bug, design, activity-tab

In [my meta profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4660897/tot-zam?tab=topactivity), the top part of the Activity tab section has an unnecessary line of space: 
[image: meta]

It looks like following line of CSS is what is causing this extra space:

```
.p-highlights .-row-first {
    min-height: 68px;
}
```

On the main profile page, there are more elements filling that section (circled in red), so this problem isn't as noticeable:
[image: main]

There still really is extra space on the main profile as well, though. The next tag badge (fuchsia circle) should really line up with the related tag progress bars. If that alignment would be fixed, the only thing then taking up an entire line is the gear icon (blue circle) used to choose to track your next badge or privilege. That icon can easily be moved, and then you have the same extra line of space on the main site activity page.

Regardless, this extra line is definitely present on Meta.

This space issues was possibly caused by this [recent nightmare fix](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351378/4660897), since all the boxes in that section are now the same height.

I know this is a minor problem, yet it is the kind of things that once seen, can never be unseen.

Comment: there's an extra `top 5% this month` message under your reputation on my screen, and the remaining empty space is not significant IMO

Comment: This is only the case when you track tag badges. On my main profile, I'm tracking my next privilege, so there isn't that extra space ([see this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxqPF.png)). If I track my next tag badge on my main profile page instead, it becomes as high as on Meta.