# Elements not aligned in profile page highlights boxes

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

Referring to [This mis-aligned border is going to give me nightmares!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351378/1115360), now some variation in the vertical placement of the next tag badge and other achievement badges in the highlight boxes is apparent.

Also, the settings gear-wheel icons are inconsistently placed:

[image: Profile page highlight boxes]

As seen in Edge and Firefox. And Chromium.

Comment: [There are also alignment issues here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgqut.jpg)

Comment: @Will I don't see any problem there: the image is neatly centred in the viewport ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯.