# Extra space under subheaders on Activity Page (SO & Meta SO)

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, design

I have observed the design carefully and after verifying it in all the standard browsers (IE, Edge, Chrome, Opera), it is now confirmed that design is not following the overall design pattern followed at Stack Overflow.

The design pattern that Stack Overflow is following doesn't have space between the sub header bottom border and the panel bottom border.

[image]

But you can see a space at the activity page like I have shown in the following images.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

### Suggested Solution:

The space is due to the extra bottom padding applied on the element.

```
.user-show-new .user-panel .subheader {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c8ccd0;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 6px;  // <---------- This is the root cause of this problem. If you comment it, you can visually see that the design is following the standard SO design pattern.
}
```

[image]

## Extra Suggestion:

For better visibility of the bottom border of menu and for consistencies throughout the SO menus and sub menus, the border of the sub header options should be increased from 1px to 2px.

```
.subtabs a, .filter a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 0 2px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;    // <------ Increase it to 2px to have a consistent layout.
    color: #6a737c;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.53333333;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 150ms cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1);
}
```

[image]

Comment: [How do you sleep at night?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350905/this-mis-aligned-border-is-going-to-give-me-nightmares) :)

Comment: bug yes.. not sure it is a feature request though

Comment: @suraj yeah I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestion! We've wanted to fix this area for far too long but we've been unable to for varying reasons. As part of some profile housekeeping, we've *finally* been able to correct some of these visual oddities. Here's what these panels will now look like:

[image]